# Clean way to move python 3.6 venv between machines?

Tags: python-3.x, pip, virtualenv

I need to copy a python 3.6 environment to another machine(using windows 10 on both). There are several questions addressing this to some extent, but they all seem to come to the same conclusions which either isn't working for me or I am missing something. Basically, everyone says use `virtualenv <path\to\env> --system-site-packages` to make and environment. Activate the environment with `pip freeze > requirements.txt`, then on my other machine make a new virtual env again, active it and run `pip install -r requirements.txt`.

I could not get the first step to work, because I had python 2.7 also installed, and the `--python` option also didn't work. I did some digging and found this command, which worked: `python -m venv <path/to/env>` once in my (activated) venv, I ran `pip freeze > requirements.txt` which worked fine, but when I went to install into another "blank" virtual environment-with `pip install -r requirements.txt` -I got the following error: `"No matching distribution found for backports.datetime-timestamp==1.0.2.dev0"`. After looking into that, it seems that the requirements.txt file copied all of my libraries including the built in ones....At least that was what it seems like. I am wondering if there is a way to have `pip freeze` ignore built in libraries, or otherwise if there is a better to move virtual envs? I could also zip the whole virtual environment up, but it seemed like most people discouraged doing that; if anyone could also shed some light on why this is a bad practice that would also be useful. Or did I just mess up some step along the way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed by using `pip3 freeze requirements.txt`

Comment: You can press the checkmark to the left to mark your question as solved.